# Is it true that $6n^2+p$ gives primes for $n=0,1,2,\dots,p-1$ iff $Q(\sqrt{-6p})$ has class number $4$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number, are the following statements true?

> 1.Quadratics of the form $6n^2+p$ gives primes for $n=0,1,2,\dots,p-1$ iff $Q(\sqrt{-6p})$ has class number $4$. And all such primes are $p\in\{5,7,13,17\}.$
>
> 2.Quadratics of the form $10n^2+p$ gives primes for $n=0,1,2,\dots,p-1$ iff $Q(\sqrt{-10p})$ has class number $4$. And all such primes are $p\in\{3,7,13,19\}.$

I know that quadratics of the form $2n^2+p$ gives primes for $n=0,1,2,\dots,p-1$ iff $Q(\sqrt{-2p})$ has class number $2$. And all such primes are $p\in\{3,5,11,29\}.$ See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html).

Comment: According to MAGMA, your two statements hold for $p < 10^4$.

Comment: One consideration: Class 4 is the _minimum_ possible class number $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-6p}]$ or $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-10p}]$. It corresponds to a minimal set of quadratic forms for the relevant discriminants, which could feed into the primality for $0<n<p$.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify or disprove the "if" part of your claim easily with a computer because the only quadratic imaginary fields with class number $4$ are given by $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ where $d$ is one in the list

14,17,21,30,33,34,39,42,46,55,
57,70,73,78,82,85,93,97,102,130,
133,142,155,177,190,193,195,203,219,253,
259,291,323,355,435,483,555,595,627,667,
715,723,763,795,955,1003,1027,1227,1243,1387,1411,1435,1507,1555.

Here is a [list of imaginary quadratic fields with small class numbers](http://www.numbertheory.org/classnos/).

Comment: You are right; I edited the answer accordingly.